# SELECT second before most recent Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

After a CTE with several joins, sub-queries, etc. I have a table pulling appointments that occurred, their location, the participants, the dates, ...

One of the columns I have `MAX(DATE)` to pull the most recent visit date.

How can I do a `SELECT` clause to see the visit date that occurred right before the most recent one?

Would I place it in a subquery?

Comment: Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46475689/edit) your question to include the query that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
select *
from (
select *, row_number() over(order by [date]) as rownum
from myresult
) T where rownum = 2
```

Comment: I already have an existing query. I just want to add this as a column. Do I add your query as a INNER JOIN?

Comment: If you already have an existing query you should include it in your question ;)

Comment: I should. It's just +200 lines long

Comment: @kazzi - put your query as a subquery instead of "myresult"

Comment: you can do `;with myresult as (<... your big query ...>) <... provided answer ...>`. That basically wraps up your existing query in a CTE which you can reference just like it were its own table. You can then implement this answer immediately after that . You might have/want to change some of the names, but the basic structure should do

Comment: Just be carefull about ties, two results with same date. Which one is the second one.